# Error with ffmpeg - undefined whole

Tags: c++, linux, linker, ffmpeg

I compiled ffmpeg on clear lubuntu and whiled attaching libs to my project in eclipse I got bunch of errors:

```
/usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(mov.o): In function `mov_read_sbgp':
/root/ffmpeg/libavformat/mov.c:2039: undefined reference to `av_malloc'
/usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(mov.o): In function `mov_read_dac3':
/root/ffmpeg/libavformat/mov.c:647: undefined reference to `avpriv_ac3_channel_layout_tab'
/usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(mov.o): In function `mov_read_tfhd':
/root/ffmpeg/libavformat/mov.c:2559: undefined reference to `av_log'
/usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(mov.o): In function `mov_read_stts':
/root/ffmpeg/libavformat/mov.c:1908: undefined reference to `av_malloc'
/root/ffmpeg/libavformat/mov.c:1921: undefined reference to `av_log'
/root/ffmpeg/libavformat/mov.c:1925: undefined reference to `av_log'
/usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(mov.o): In function `mov_read_stss':
/root/ffmpeg/libavformat/mov.c:1790: undefined reference to `av_malloc'
/usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(mov.o): In function `mov_read_stsc':
/root/ffmpeg/libavformat/mov.c:1712: undefined reference to `av_malloc'
```

Its only a part of output..Could somoone help me with that staff? I stucked here, thx.

Also I give u some info about ld --verbose -l avformat:

```
attempt to open /usr/i686-linux-gnu/lib32/libavformat.so failed
attempt to open /usr/i686-linux-gnu/lib32/libavformat.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib32/libavformat.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib32/libavformat.a failed
attempt to open /lib32/libavformat.so failed
attempt to open /lib32/libavformat.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib32/libavformat.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib32/libavformat.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavformat.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libavformat.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libavformat.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libavformat.a succeeded
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

Everything is going to be problem with avutil....all undefined reference comes from files of libavutil. But I have no idea why and what to do.

Comment: Is `libavutil` the only library file of `ffmpeg`? I suppose it has additional dependencies on other libraries. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430306/gcc-undefined-reference-error/22431021#22431021), he compiles project with `-lavfilter` and `-lavcodec` (and `-lpthread` also).

Comment: It doesnt change anything...

Comment: Please provide the arguments you pass to the compiler.

Comment: U mean while comiling project not ffmpeg?    g++ -L/usr/local/lib/ -o "test"  ./src/test.o   -lpthread -lavfilter -lavcodec -lavutil -lavformat
./src/test.o: In function `main':

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc). Try to move `-lavutil` to the end of your libraries list.

Comment: Did it witchout any progress. I think livavformat depend on libavutil. What is more  I compile this ffmpeg 3 times on fresh system and always got the same error while linking into a project

Comment: Hah... You gotta righ..)  now I am dealing with undefined vpx_codec_error -- tryinf find out that lib.

Comment: You can post answer to your own question and accept it so that it would not be "unanswered" in search anymore.

Comment: I will do it but i need wait 8h - no reputation here! Thx

Answer (score 1):

By given help i managed to  solve problem so let me share with You.
For compilation guid

[How to set up ffmpeg for dev](http://wiki.razuna.com/display/ecp/FFmpeg+Installation+for+Ubuntu)

use this linking order:

```
avdevice
avfilter
postproc
avformat
avcodec
rt
dl
Xfixes
Xext
X11
asound
SDL
vorbisenc
vorbis
theoraenc
theoradec
ogg
opencore-amrwb
opencore-amrnb
z
rt
swresample
swscale
avutil
m
z
swresample
faac
mp3lame
vpx
x264
xvidcore
pthread
```